# Three unknowns, the last TWO rows of the matrix contain ALL zeros.

Tags: gaussian-elimination

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the "generic solution" to this matrix by using Gaussian Method by REF. The answer on the back of the book is: $(x,y,\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}y)$. I really don't understand the concept behind this answer so if anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it! thank you. I've attached a photo of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But that doesn't require down voting the question to -5

Answer (score 0):

$$2x+3y+2z=1$$

and there is no other constraints as $0=0$ trivially holds.

Then $$z=\frac{1-3y-2x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-x-\frac{3y}{2}$$

Hence, given $x,y$, the $z$ must satisfies $z=\frac{1-3y-2x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-x-\frac{3y}{2}.$